# Django Admin no such table

Tags: python, django

I've created a model Language. I did the `makemigrations` and `migrate` part. Everything went fine. I registered my db in the settings file.

When I click on the language table on the admin page I get this:

```
OperationalError at /admin/testdb/language/
no such table: testdb_language
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/testdb/language/
Django Version: 1.9.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: testdb_language
Exception Location: /Users/nep/Documents/Development/Private/testdjango/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 323
Python Executable:  /Users/nep/Documents/Development/Private/testdjango/myvenv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/nep/Documents/Development/Private/testdjango',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/nep/Documents/Development/Private/testdjango/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

My model is defined like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Oxn(models.Model):
    objectId = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    picture = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Language(models.Model):
    objectId = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I don't see the problem. Can someone help me?

EDIT:

This is the output of the migrations:

```
(myvenv) ➜  gins4udjango python manage.py showmigrations       
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
ginsdb
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

EDIT

0001_initial.py from migrations has following content:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.5 on 2016-04-29 14:51
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Country',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('objectId', models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Gin',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('objectId', models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)),
                ('alcohol', models.FloatField(blank=True, default=None, null=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('picture', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='GinLocal',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('objectId', models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)),
                ('origin', models.TextField()),
                ('serve', models.TextField()),
                ('aroma', models.TextField()),
                ('country', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='ginsdb.Country', to_field='objectId')),
                ('gin', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='ginsdb.Gin', to_field='objectId')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Language',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('objectId', models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)),
                ('code', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
                ('language', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Type',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('objectId', models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)),
                ('typeName', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('language', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='ginsdb.Language', to_field='objectId')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='ginlocal',
            name='language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='ginsdb.Language', to_field='objectId'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='ginlocal',
            name='types',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(to='ginsdb.Type'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='country',
            name='language',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='ginsdb.Language', to_field='objectId'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: What does `./manage.py showmigrations` display? What are the contents of your migrations for the `testdb` app?

Comment: I've added them to the topic

Comment: Which app are `Language` and `Oxn` in? Is it really called `testdb`?

Comment: Sorry I renamed the testdb to ginsdb so they are both in the ginsdb

Comment: What are the contents of the `ginsdb` `0001_initial` migration?

Comment: I've added the contents to the topic.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0001_initial` migration for the `ginsdb` app contains the `Language` model, so it should have been created when ran that migration.

If you are still developing and don't have any important data, then the easiest thing to do is to drop the database, and rerun the migrations for a fresh database. Just delete the sqlite database file, then rerun `./manage.py migrate`.

If you need to keep the database, then you could try creating the models manually, but this will be trickier. You can view the required SQL to create the models by running:

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate ginsdb 0001_initial
```

Comment: I did but still that problem.

Comment: Thank you. I just had to do manage.py migrate auth before I did my own migration. So just delete the .sql file and redo everything :-). Thank you

Comment: If you change the dependencies to `dependencies = [(u'auth', '__first__')]` in your migration file, then Django will run them in the correct order, and you won't have to manually run the auth migration first.

Comment: Thank you for the tip :)